# How to join multiple column using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need one help. I need to join two table using multiple column in codeigniter. I am explaining my table below.

> pt_car_locations

```
id     pickup_location_id       dropoff_location_id     price

   1           21                           22                100

   2           23                           24                200
```

> pt_locations

```
 id              location

  21              Cappa

  22              United

  23              Mascut

  24              ABCD
```

Here I need to retrieve the pickup and drop location by joining both table. I am explaining query below.

```
$this->db->select('cl.pickup_location_id,cl.dropoff_location_id,cl.price,l.id,l.location');
$this->db->from('pt_car_locations as cl');
$this->db->join('pt_locations as l', 'cl.pickup_location_id = l.id', 'inner');
```

Here I need to join both column and get the both location in each row.

Answer (score 1):

could be you need  the join twice  one with table alias l  and one with table alias  l2

```
$this->db->select('cl.pickup_location_id,cl.dropoff_location_id,cl.price,l.id,l.location');
$this->db->from('pt_car_locations as cl');
$this->db->join('pt_locations as l', 'cl.pickup_location_id = l.id', 'inner');
$this->db->join('pt_locations as l2', 'cl.dropoff_location_id = l2.id', 'inner');
```